# Unable to make https requests via proxy using,php and curl

Tags: php, curl, https, proxy

We are Unable to make https requests via proxy using php and curl. We tried to make a simple curl request from PHP to https://google.com and we get message 'Request could not be processed.Invalid response received by proxy or gateway server'.The same request to http:/google.com works fine. We are also able to successfully call any https url from curl command line. below is our curl request. Proxy doesn't require login and we have openssl installed in PHP. Any replies are appreciated.

```
$url='https://google.com';
$handle = curl_init();
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_PROXY, 'some proxy');
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, 80);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);
$data = curl_exec($handle);
```

Comment: Does your proxy server require credentials?

Comment: Nope it doesnt require any credentials.

Comment: Okay.. then you should set `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` to `true`.

Comment: I think you're also missing `CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL` to `true`.

Comment: Didnt work, same error message. added it like below curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);

Comment: And the `CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL` option?

Comment: nope didn't work, tried with httpproxytunnel too.

Comment: Strange. Try debugging with `curl_getinfo`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php

Comment: when I print curl_getinfo, curl_error, $data etc they are all empty. The only error that comes up on the screen is 'Proxy Error': 'Request could not be processed.Invalid response received by proxy or gateway server'.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, 80);
```

to:

```
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, 443);
```

Since [https](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Secure) traffic is on port 443.

Comment: tested by changing port to 443, got the same 502 error Request could not be processed.Invalid response received by proxy or gateway server.

Answer (score 0):

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

It works for me .